# How to allocate LinkedList comes from C binding in Rust?

Tags: memory, rust, linked-list

I'm trying to understand Rust' memory mechanism, especially how it works when you need it to interoperate with C code.

Here I have small C code represents a linked list and a function prints its `attr` to stdout:

```c
// this is wrapper.h
typedef struct elem {
    int attr;
    struct elem *next;
} elem;

typedef struct wrapper {
    char name[16];
    struct elem *first_elem;
} wrapper;

void print_all_attrs(wrapper *w);

// -----
// and this is how wrapper.c looks like:
#include <stdio.h>

#include "wrapper.h"

void print_all_attrs(wrapper *w) {
    printf("NAME = %s\n", w->name);

    elem *elem = w->first_elem;
    while(elem != NULL) {
        printf("ATTR = %d\n", elem->attr);
        elem = elem->next;
    }
}
```

We all know how to prepare a `wrapper` that can hold a linkedlist of `elem` which is created dynamically: we need to create a `wrapper` variable, then a logic allocates an area in heap for every `elem`, assigns the first one into `wrapper->first_elem` and then others to previous' `next` pointer. here the code does exactly same thing:

```
void main() {
    wrapper w = {
        .name = "ABCD",
    };

    elem *prev = NULL;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        elem *new = malloc(sizeof(elem));
        new->attr = i;
        if(w.first_elem == NULL) {
            w.first_elem = new;
            prev = new;
            continue;
        }
        prev->next = new;
        prev = prev->next;
    }

    print_all_attrs(&w);

    // CLEARING HEAP STUFF HERE...
}
```

So, in Rust, I'm trying to use those definitions by generating code `bindgen` and `cc` libraries, I'm skipping these details right now.

If I want to allocate something into heap, I know I can use `Box` but it doesn't work at all because it drops when it goes out scope. take a look below code that exits with segmentation fault:

```
unsafe {
        let mut prev: *mut xxx::elem = w.first_elem;
        for n in 0..10 {
            let mut elem = Box::new(xxx::elem {
                attr: n,
                next: ptr::null_mut(),
            });

            if w.first_elem.is_null() {
                w.first_elem = &mut *elem;
                prev = &mut *elem;
                continue;
            }

            (*prev).next = &mut *elem;
            prev = (*prev).next;
        }

        xxx::print_all_attrs(&mut w);
    }
```

I managed to use Layout and alloc, but these guys bring a cost that I need to dealloc the things after use:

```
unsafe {
        use std::alloc::{Layout, alloc};
        let mut prev: *mut xxx::elem = w.first_elem;
        for n in 0..10 {
            let layout = Layout::new::<xxx::elem>();
            let mut p = alloc(layout) as *mut xxx::elem;
            (*p).attr = n;
            (*p).next = ptr::null_mut();

            if w.first_elem.is_null() {
                w.first_elem = p;
                prev = p;
                continue;
            }

            (*prev).next = p;
            prev = (*prev).next;
        }

        xxx::print_all_attrs(&mut w);
        // dealloc stuff here.
    }
```

I wonder that if there is another possible way to do that without using `Layout` and its friends? I see this is one of the proper way to make it but it makes me feel this is not the expected "Rust-way".

Comment: [`Box::into_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.into_raw) - but please note that you cannot deallocate this on the C side.

Comment: @PitaJ great, that works! thank you so much, but as you mentioned it brings same cost as well, I have to deallocate by myself right after using it. btw, it is better use than layout and its friends (:

Comment: `Box::into_raw()` is just simpler. It too uses `Layout` and `std::alloc` under the hood, just less work and less unsafe. Prefer it if possible, use manual allocation only if necessary.

Comment: Also note that your code with `Layout` is UB.